# In a byte, each additional bit doubles the representable states, but does it double memory?

Tags: memory

A friend asked me whether adding a single bit more memory doubles the amount of memory you have, as the bit doubles the amount of representable states.

My brain got stuck thinking about it.

Doubling the amount of bits doubles the amount of states we can simultaneously represent.

Am I performing a category error. What does it mean to double memory?

Comment: You need to differentiate between a memory address and an address space.  Adding a bit to a memory address adds one bit of additional storage to store that memory address.  Adding a bit to a (theoretical) address space doubles the memory that could potentially be inside it, e.g. a 12-bit address space allows access to 4096 different items, and a 13-bit address space allows access to 8192 different items (twice as many as 12-bit).  (The size of the items being addressed can also sometimes be varied, though bytes are a common unit of addressability.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a linear increase in memory and an exponential increase in representational state.

Each additional bit is an additional multiplicand of 2 in the number of possible values, thus moving to the next power of 2.

```
0 (2^1 values: 2)
00 (2^2 values: 4)
000 (2^3 values: 8)
0000 (2^4 values: 16)
00000 (2^5 values: 32)
```

Doubling memory usually means doubling the number of memory addresses that an application uses, or doubling the amount of RAM used. It doesn't mean doubling the number of possible values.

Calculating the number of possible values that a piece of memory can represent is easy: `2^n` where `n` is the number of bits in that piece of memory.

The number of possible values in a 32 `int` variable is 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 possible values. To "double" that memory is to use a 64 bit `long`, which has 2^64 values: 1.8446744e+19.

Comment: So if I say my program needs twice the memory I'm actually saying it needs some exponential amount of extra state?

Comment: That's correct. Your application needs an exponential increase in possible values, but a linear increase in memory addresses.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that your friend has wandered into terminology confusion based on reusing the same term for multiple purposes.

If I have 8 bits of memory, I have 8 bits of memory, nothing more.  They can store one byte, which represents any one of 256 possible states.  If you add one more bit of memory, it doubles the number of possible states, but it can still only hold one such state.

However, to represent *all* of those 8-bit states at the same time, I would need 256 bytes.  When you have a system that uses *8-bit memory addressing*, (or, more commonly these days, 32-bit or 64-bit memory addressing,) it means that you use an 8-bit number to represent a location in memory, and you can therefore have up to 256 possible memory locations available to your addressing scheme.  (Which is why no one uses such a small memory addressing system: you'd run out of addresses too quickly.  They use 32- or 64-bit systems, which is something very different from having only 32 or 64 bits of memory.)

When people say they have a 64-bit system, that's usually what it means: their system uses 64-bit values for memory addressing, giving their system the potential to support `2^64` bytes of memory.  So far, no computer has anywhere near that much actual memory available; it's only in the last few years that we've broken past the 32-bit limit, which is 4 GB.  The 64-bit limit is the square of that, approximately 16 billion GB.

Answer (score 1):

It doubles the amount of memory locations you can address.  Perhaps that's where you are getting confused.  This is why computers are now mostly 64-bit.  In a 32-bit system, the memory was bounded at 4GB.  With a 64-bit addresses we can use much much more.

If I have a 1 bit memory, adding one bit doubles my memory.  If i have a 2 bit memory, adding a bit only adds 50%.  That's the other (less useful) way to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your hands.

With the five fingers on one hand you can represent 32 different numbers using a binary encoding.

With the ten fingers on both hands you can represent 32 x 32 = 1,024 different numbers.

Double the memory means the number of possible states is squared.

And I'd love to see you trying to represent a million numbers using fingers and toes.

Comment: Anyone who can achieve this feat and still retain their modesty and composure might consider applying for the post of Librarian at the Unseen University, Ankh-Morepork!